# A word reminiscent of "matriculate"

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word that means "to move slowly though a process or system." I was writing an email and I used the word "matriculate", but it clearly is not the word for which I'm looking (football announcers non-withstanding). Is there a word that sounds like matriculate that means what I want here or am I way off base? I wonder if the fact that it sounds like "trickle" is what has me wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of **percolate**?

> Water slowly percolates through the soil.